# Powershell MS Project Fields Value

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, project, ms-project

I'm facing with problem to get value from project customfield using powershell iterating through all project on site using:

```
$site = Get-SPSite "<mysite>/sites/pwa"    
foreach($web in $site.AllWebs)
{
$web.Fileds['customfieldname'].value?
}
```

is there any snapin to get those values ?

Comment: Check what `$site.AllWebs` actually is... A collection of ?? and I don't think it will have elements called `Fileds`

Comment: $site.AllWebs is collection of project webs